# Multi-highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, is there a way to highlight HTML and JavaScript (or any other combination of languages) at the same time?

Comment: Not as far as I know, though seeing as there is something of a plugin development community, so it might be something worth suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ already highlights HTML and JavaScript simultaneously, provided your JavaScript code is placed within `<script>` tags in your markup and you're editing a file that's being highlighted as HTML.

It really depends on the languages you want highlighted. Some languages naturally co-exist, for example HTML and JavaScript, or HTML and PHP (even a combination of HTML, JavaScript *and* PHP). Others may not, so Notepad++ won't be able to highlight them together. I can't imagine that you'll be able to change this behavior other than through plugins or hacking the source.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that combinations of languages can somehow be configured via the UI (as opposed to writing plugins or hacking a source code).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to configure Notepad++ to use CSS and JS markup highlighting and autocompletion for JSP Files but failed. Now I excluded the CSS and JS into seperated files and use templates that create new files everytime when the JS or CSS files are touched. It's a Grunt watch task that fires 'grunt-includes'. Works fine for me.